# Использование Angular-translate c Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Делаю локализацию для приложения.
[Вот моя ветка.](https://github.com/igorlimansky/esteem/tree/develop)
Работал [по этому туториалу.](http://robferguson.org/2015/07/22/internationalisation-i18n-and-localisation-l10n-for-ionic-apps/)
Запускаю с помощью `ionic serve` и в браузере консоли выдает следующие ошибки:

```
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/angular/angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://192.168.1.66:8100/bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2http://192.168.1.66:8100/src/app.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
lib.js:26793 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=translateFilterProvider%20%3C-%20translateFilter
    at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:13438:12
    at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17787:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17940:39)
    at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17792:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:17940:39)
    at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:32696:24
    at isStateless (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:27441:12)
    at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:27498:33)
    at http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:27452:7
    at forEach (http://192.168.1.66:8100/js/lib.js:13691:20) <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios">
```

Что я делаю не так?
Если не можете помочь, то посоветуйте, что почитать на эту тему?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы забыли сделать

```
bower install
```